# How can i get the last item of a orderBy in dexie.js?

Tags: javascript, dexie

I must admit, I am a bit confused about when an operation needs to bed done on a collection and when it needs to be done on a table in dexie js.

So I am not sure, whether this is the right approach (which is not working anyway) to achieve my goal.

What I'd like to do is sort a table named "products" in the database "shopDb" by the field "updated_at", and get the last item on the result, like this:

```
shopDb.products.orderBy('updated_at').last().then((result) => { // stuff });
```

This code already crashes on sortBy because:

```
TypeError: shopDb.products.orderBy is not a function
```

I must be missing something fundamental here.

Comment: See if https://jsfiddle.net/dfahlander/3tf5r0cu helps.

Comment: No, it does not help, sorry.

Comment: I am sorry. Here is the corrected one using `orderBy` - https://jsfiddle.net/0qgr9zto/

Comment: If you post it as an answer, I will mark it. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. I am not sure what fixed it for you because I saw the `orderBy` method. If it was a overlook/spelling mistake or any such thing, you can close this. If you think your finding can help others, post an answer.